# accumulate() with operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, accumulate

I have a question concerning accumulate() and operator overloading.

I have a class Order that contains

```
private:
Customer cust;
std::vector<Purchase> vP;
```

and a class Purchase with

```
private:
    string name;
    double unit_price;
    int count;
```

I want to use accumulate() to add together the prices of all of the Purchases (which means unit_price*count) in a vector with Orders. My solution with overloading the + operator of Order doesn't work. This is how it looks like:

```
double Order::operator+(Order& p) {

    double gesamt{};
    gesamt=(gesamtpreisEinerPerson()+p.gesamtpreisEinerPerson());

    return gesamt;
}

double Order::gesamtpreisEinerPerson(){
    double kosten=0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<vP.size(); ++i){
    kosten+=(vP.at(i).getPrice()*vP.at(i).getCount());        
    }   
    return kosten;
}
```

and for accumulate I call

```
double totalPrice(vector<Order> vectOrd) {

    double d = accumulate(vectOrd.begin(), vectOrd.end(), 0.0);

    return d;
    }
```

So my question is: Why can't I solve the accumulate problem with operator overloading? Doesn't it work in general or is there something wrong with my code? Thanks very much in advance!

The error message is

```
In file included from main.cpp:5:
In file included from ./global.hpp:16:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/numeric:81:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'Order')
        __init = __init + *__first;
                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
./global.hpp:272:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::accumulate<std::__1::__wrap_iter<Order *>, double>' requested here
    double d = accumulate(vectOrd.begin(), vectOrd.end(), 0.0);
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:743:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Order'
operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1163:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Order'
operator+(typename move_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const move_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1576:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__wrap_iter<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Order'
operator+(typename __wrap_iter<_Iter>::difference_type __n,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3698:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3711:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'double'
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs , const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3723:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Order'
operator+(_CharT __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3734:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3746:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3760:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3768:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3776:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3784:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'double'
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs , basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3792:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Order'
operator+(_CharT __lhs, basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>&& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3801:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3809:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'double'
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: Might or might not be related, but by taking `Order&` and not making the function `const`, you're saying no one is allowed to call it unless the LHS is a non-const object and the RHS is not temporary and not const. Those are very abnormal requirements for an operator that shouldn't be modifying any of its operands.

Comment: _doesn't work_ does mean what?

Comment: Oh yes thanks, I fixed that to double operator+(const Order& p). Thanks!

Comment: The code doesn't compile and I get the following error message: https://imgur.com/a/hu7cl

Comment: Copy&paste the error messages.

Comment: ok error message is pasted.

Answer (score 2):

The accumulator predicate should have signature `double(double, const Order&)`:

Easy way to do your accumulation would be:

```
double d = accumulate(vectOrd.begin(),
                      vectOrd.end(),
                      0.0,
                      [](double acc, const Order& order) {
                          return acc + order.gesamtpreisEinerPerson();
                      });
```

If you really want to use operator overloading, you have to implement (the free function):

```
double operator+ (double d, const Order& order)
{
    return d + order.gesamtpreisEinerPerson();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry I'm still a noob at programming. What exactly is the accumulator predicate? And is there a way to solve the problem with operator overloading?

Comment: The accumulator predicate is the 4th argument of `std::accumulate`.

Comment: I'm using operator+() as a member function and it won't let me take 3 parameters.

Comment: I said as **free function** (non member function)... left operand should be `double`. if you use member function, first parameter is `Order`.